# gdata youtube feed for auto-generated channels

Tags: youtube-api

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to get a gdata feed for an auto-generated youtube channel, aka a "Topic."

For example, here's the JPop Channel:

> http://www.youtube.com/channel/HC9BkB0bbvR-4

Were this a user, I know I could get a feed like: `http:// gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/{username}/uploads`. But since it's not a user, that doesn't work.

I know I could do a search like: `http:// gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&q=jpop`, but that's not exactly the same thing.

This question was asked before on the [old Youtube Developer Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/youtube-api-gdata/topics/youtube-api-gdata/SB3Jbengfvg/RDzQeZdh_lEJ), but at the time it wasn't available.

I've looked all through the API docs to see if that's changed, but can't find any reference to it.

I was hoping someone here might know if it's changed, and the docs haven't been updated, or if there's an expected ETA for that feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can interact with auto-generated topic channels (those that begin with `HC`) by subscribing to them like any other channel.

If you just want to get a list of videos associated with the channel, though, you need to use the forthcoming v3 of the API, and you can do a search based on the underlying topic. You can get the topic id(s) related to a given channel using `channels.list(id=CHANNEL_ID)`:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=topicDetails&id=HC9BkB0bbvR-4

(v3 isn't publicly released as of right now, so you need to use the Google APIs Explorer.)

That returns (Freebase) topic id `/m/025g__`, which you can then use to do a `search.list(topicId=TOPIC_ID, q=BLAH, type=video)`

```
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&type=video&q=j+pop&topicId=%252Fm%252F025g__
```

Unfortunately, you can't do a search that just specifies a `topicId=` without a `q=` right now in v3, but that's a bug that will hopefully be fixed soon. So you do need to specify something meaningful for the `q=` parameter for the time being, and I'm just using `j pop`.

Comment: Do you know if this bug is still unsolved? I'm looking for a way to search with a topicId whitout a q=

Comment: It's possible to specify a `topicId` without a `q` now: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&topicId=%252Fm%252F025g__&type=video&_h=1&

Comment: How do you get the channel id in the first place? The url structure shows a different channel id. JPOP for example is this: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWXsUjtAGn-x_tM5L1Xk2xw