# gdata youtube feed for auto-generated show

Tags: youtube-api

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to get a gdata feed for an auto-generated youtube channel, aka a "Show."

For example, : http://www.youtube.com/show/dharmayudham

Were this a user, I know I could get a feed like: `http:// gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/{username}/uploads`. But since it's not a user, that doesn't work.

I know I could do a search like: `http:// gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&q=dharmayudham`, but that's not exactly the same thing.

I've looked all through the API docs to see if that's changed, but can't find any reference to it.

I was hoping someone here might know if it's changed, and the docs haven't been updated, or if there's an expected ETA for that feature?

Comment: possible duplicate of [gdata youtube feed for auto-generated channels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001410/gdata-youtube-feed-for-auto-generated-channels)

Answer (score 0):

This is documented at https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_movies_and_shows#Shows_Seasons_and_Episodes

To get a list of shows associated with the channel `STARVIJAY`, you can request https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/STARVIJAY/shows?v=2

That response includes a link to https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/shows/q7aPMCyJ0aE/content?v=2, which in turn includes a link to https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/seasons/CWqNC-MR-RA/episodes?v=2

That last link includes the episodes in that show.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Similar like, can you please help me to post for channels? http://www.youtube.com/channel/SBae7jiISxYlc